# How many natural number n that are satisfied $(2^n- n^2)(mod 7)=0$.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I want to know about combinatorial way to solve this problem.

The problem is

How many natural number $n<1000$ that are satisfied

$(2^n- n^2)\pmod 7=0$.

I solved like remainders that $2^n$ divided by 7 are have 3-cycles and those of remainders that $n^2$ devided by 7 have 7-cycles. So $n$ has 21-cycle and so on. But someone said there are combinatorial way to solve this and I want to know but I've got no idea.

Comment: Your solution is combinatorial.

Comment: @Berci Thank you for answering but he said not that kind of combinatorial. Like Number of integer soluton(x,y,z) that satisfied |x|+|y|+|z|=4. I don't have information about 'combinatorial way' more than that.

Comment: "someone said there are combinatorial ways to solve this" so why not ask the person who said that?

Comment: @GerryMyerson He said me to think about this. So I'm still think about this problem oftenly but I can't find.

Comment: The first few solutions are 2,
4,
5,
6,
10,
15,
23,
25, ...

Answer (score 1):

Since you observe that $2^n \bmod 7$ gives a 3-cycle, you can consider just three cases corresponding to the different residues$\bmod 3$.

For $n\equiv 0 \bmod 3$ you have $2^n\equiv 1 \bmod 7$ thus $n^2\equiv 1 \bmod 7$.  Then $n\in\{1,6\}\bmod 7$ and you use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to render $n\in\{15,6\}\bmod 21$ (same order as the $\bmod 7$ resudues).

For each of $n\equiv 1\bmod 3$ and $n\equiv 2\bmod 3$ you get two more residues $\bmod 21$ and then you form the union of the results from the three cases.

Comment: Thank you for answering but I need differen way.......

Comment: Not sure how you would get the number of values w/o first rendering the proper mod $21$ residues.  I can see how you would derive that $2/7$ of all natural numbers would work, but the answer for $n$ up to $143×7=1001$ is $287$ not $143×2=286$.  You need the proper mod $21$ residues to pick that difference up.

Comment: I'd got 287 too but I thought this is not the solution of his.Howerver, I think it is one of the great solution of problem. Thank you for give me your opinion.